# How to simply xcopy a folder into another keeping the structure?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-transfer, cmd.exe, xcopy

Suppose I have the following structure and the current working directory is `root`:

```
root
    - sub1
         file1.xml
         file2.xml
    - sub2
         file3.css
    - _target
         {is an empty folder}
    run.bat
```

I want to use `xcopy` to copy `sub1` under `_target` keeping the structure. So the result is:

```
- _target
    - sub1
        file1.xml
        file2.xml
```

However when I try to add parameters (i.e. any combination of `/I`, `/S`, `/E`) to `xcopy` I always end up with this:

```
- _target
    file1.xml
    file2.xml
```

What are the correct parameters to achieve the one above (`sub1` in `_target` with its contents)?

I tried adding `\` at the end of both source and destination folders to mimic unix `cp`'s magic behavior, but that didn't help either.

**Please note that I'm looking for a solution that doesn't unnecessarily duplicate the folder name in the arguments (*this is what I mean by "simply" in the title*), I know that `xcopy sub1 _target\sub1 /I` works!**

As a **last resort** a `robocopy` answer may be acceptable, but I would really prefer `xcopy` without duplicating the parameter.

Comment: so you want to copy the directory with its contents, rather than just its contents..  I don't know,  `move` works like that. move b a, will move the b directory into a.  But you know re xcopy, a workaround is to do `md thedirectory` then xcopy the contents of your source directory into that.

Comment: All very well if you want to copy the directory somewhere else with the same name. But suppose you wanted to copy the contents of a directory into a directory of another name.  The fact that with xcopy you specify the directory whose contents you want to copy, that gives you that flexibility.  On many occasions it may not be the same name twice.

Comment: And if you think that due to the occasions where it is the same name twice, it is then too many keystrokes, and a shortcoming inherited from DOS, well, it's not like linux philosophy is minimal keystrokes, Try to list just directories not files, in linux.. you need some find command, whereas in CMD or DOS it's just `dir /ad`

Comment: Also, if the dest directory doesn't exist  then xcopy prompts you whether it's a file or directory, so it's easier to just 'md' it beforehand.  And furthermore, with DOS or CMD, if you do DIR blah* then you know what it is going to do.. it will list all files/directories beginning with blah.  But with linux if you do ls blah*  or ls /etc/ssh*  then unless you know the directory structure before doing the command, you don't know whether the output is going to be the files starting with blah, or the contents of a directory starting with blah.  So linux has some serious shortcomings IMO.

Comment: You make the directory first, not just so you don't have to type it (you can avoid typing it again by copy/paste which is very quick if you turn on quickedit mode in the cmd window), but you also make the directory first so xcopy doesn't prompt you asking if it's an F-Folder or a D-Directory. And when you have made the directory prior to the xcopy, you can use tab again. Not need to even copy/paste, let alone typing the long folder name again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26251/discussion-between-barlop-and-twisterrob).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that /S and /E contradict eachother. Either use /S (all, except empty folders) or use /E (all, including empty folders).

I bet you want to use the /E one, so your xcopy would be:

```
xcopy sub1 _target\sub1 /I /E
```

Comment: Quoting from the question: "**I'm looking for a solution that doesn't unnecessarily duplicate the folder name in the arguments [...] I know that `xcopy sub1 _target\sub1 /I` works!**" ... so what you contribute to `/E` actually has the effect because you added `\sub1`; that's why it creates the subdir I want.

Comment: Also `/I /S /E` was just one of many combinations I tried, I clarified that.